# How I can space the number with PHP command?

Tags: php

I want to code the PHP for spacing the number, example:

`$number = "55375911";`

So this number should to space to 2-digit and 6-digit, it shows so: "55 3759 11". How I can code this?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @ezzzCash As per his example, it already is a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also use substring (if the number is always the same length):

```
$number = "55375911";
$number_f = substr($number, 0, 2) . " " . substr($number, 2, 4) . " " . substr($number, 6, 6);

echo $number_f; // "55 3759 11"
```

Comment: You could leave off the last '6' in the last substr, so it simply includes all of the remaining numbers beyond the 6th place (second space).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$number = "55375911";
$number = str_split($number, 2);
$number=$number[0].' '.$number[1].''.$number[2].' '.$number[3];
echo $number;
```

This code will work for you for this kind of numbers.

The output is :

```
55 3759 11
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the OP wants code for equally spaced numbers for a given number string and the specified digits. The number is give is $number in the code below and $digit is the number of digits each group should have.

```
$number = "455375911";
$length = strlen($number);
$digit = 3;
$curlen = $length;
$cur = "";
echo $number . "<br />";
$last = $length%$digit;
echo "curlen $curlen<br />last " . $last . "<br />";

while($curlen >= $digit){
   $curlen = $curlen - $digit;
   $cur = substr($number, $curlen, $digit) . (empty($cur)?"":" ") . $cur;

   echo "curlen " . $curlen . "<br />";
}
if ($last){
   $cur = substr($number, 0, $last) . (empty($cur)?"":" ") . $cur;
}
else if ($curlen){
  $cur = substr($number, 0, $digit) . (empty($cur)?"":" ") . $cur;
}
echo $cur;
```